# Can I have GraphQL and GRpc communication on the same tomcat server

Tags: spring, graphql, grpc, grpc-java, graphql-java

I have a use case where a microservice communicates with front-end as well as other microservices. Currently it is using REST for all its communication. Can I expose GraphQL for frontend API's and use GRpc for internal communications in the same microservice on the same server . Can I have Grpc and Graphql implementations on the same server . I am using Spring with java 11 . Are there any examples for this .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I've used this setup for many services. But you will need to bind the gRPC server to a different port than the rest api. Check the documentation at https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/#starting-the-server. You could then expose only the rest api port to the external users and let the services communicate internally on the "trusted" gRPC channel.